# Zero-padding a 1-D tensor before or after each element. (TensorFlow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I have a 1-D tensor with **N** elements which is generated by interlacing 2 1-D vectors with **N/2** elements. How can I do this with TensorFlow?

For example, I want to generate [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] from [0, 2, 4, 6] and [1, 3, 5, 7].

I hope there could be a 1-line solution.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stack `a` and `b` as columns, then reshape it to 1d:

```
tf.reshape(tf.stack([a, b], axis=-1), [-1])
```

---

```
a = tf.constant([0, 2, 4, 6])
b = tf.constant([1, 3, 5, 7])

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
interlace = tf.reshape(tf.stack([a, b], axis=-1), [-1])

print(sess.run(interlace))
# [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
```